# Display issue in an Ionic / Angular app running in IBM mobilefirst

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

It's my first time to start working on mobile apps using angular and ionic so forgive me if this is just a simple problem. I tried googling about this issue but to no avail. Here's the problem, I tried recreating the sample app created using Ionic in the link below.

[link here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1502_maynard/1502_maynard.html)

I used the IBM MobileFirst environment to run my application. The issue is, if I didn't add a lot of < br > tags before the closing tag of the body, the display would look like the one on the right (see attached image).

[image: screenshots]

Anyone can tell me why this is happening?

Code snippet from image on the left:

```
....
....
<script src="ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<!-- New lines to load our modules -->
<script src="app/app-main.js"></script>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Code snippet for the one on the right

```
....
....
<script src="ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<!-- New lines to load our modules -->
<script src="app/app-main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically, it only gets fixed if I add lots of < br > tags before the body's closing tag. Isn't Ionic suppose to adjust to the full height? or the natural height of its contents?

Note: let me know if you cant see the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is pre-existing CSS in Worklight that may cause this. You can attempt at fixing it by adding:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

It is suggested that instead of using Hybrid apps, you'll use Cordova apps in MobileFirst 7.1. Integration with Ionic is then much simpler. Read more here: https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/03/23/working-with-ibm-mobilefirst-and-the-ionic-framework/

Comment: Thanks man it worked. I actually tried doing the body css with height set to 100% but it didnt work. Adding html made it work.Ill look into Cordova.